# Query on DB is fast, but fetching by JPARepository is slow

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, spring-data-jpa

I have following tables in DB:

`Person`, 
`Parent`, 
`GrandParent`
`Parent - Person` is `OneToMany` relation (`Person` has `parentId`)
`GrandParent - Parent` is `ManyToMany` relation (`grandparent_parent` table)

I created in `PersonRepository` which extends `JPARepository` :

```
@Query("SELECT person.uuid FROM Person person JOIN person.parent parent JOIN parent.grandparents grandparent WHERE grandparent.uuid = ?1")
Set<String> findByGrandParentId(final String parentId);
```

For fetching all ids of `Person` which are under given `GrandParent`.
This SQL is created:

```
SELECT
   person0_.uuid as col_0_0_ 
FROM
    person person0_ 
INNER JOIN
    parent parent1_ 
        on person0_.parentid=parent1_.uuid 
INNER JOIN
    grandparent_parent grandaparent_parent2_ 
        on parent1_.uuid=grandaparent_parent2_.parentid 
INNER JOIN
    grandparent parent3_ 
        on grandaparent_parent2_.grandparentid=parent3_.uuid 
WHERE
    parent3_.uuid='13906f55-441c-45bd-bef6-8beefa4119c4'
```

I logged how much time repository needs fetch data, and it took (average) *~400ms* to fetch *~400* records.
Then I execute the same SQL query on DB and each time query took no more than *50ms*.

I know that this generated query is not optimized because we can only join two tables `GRANDPARENT_PARENT` and `PERSON`, but this is not the problem here, because such query is executed also below *50ms*.

Why I have such differences between fetching by repository and fetching in db? Is it possible to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple Possibilities:

**1. The generated Query**

The generated query looks pretty fine to me. It's exactly the same as the query within your `@Query` annotation.

**2. SQL Result to Java Object conversion**

I don't know how big your tables are, but: Converting SQL Results to Java Objects takes some time. For small tables this could increase query time by 0-5%.

**3. Lazy loading**

You didn't show the code for your entities. If you have `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` relations, JPA will by default use Lazy Loading. This can really slow down everything by magnitudes.

**4. Latency**

If you execute the SQL Query on the same machine where the SQL DB is, but your Java Application communicates over network with the SQL DB, it can result in much slower queries, too.

(5. Wrong kind of DB. Seems like you build an object graph. Maybe have a look at Neo4j **`;-)`**)

Comment: 1. As I said, I can change it to one join, but query is good, as you described.

Comment: 2,3. As you see I fetch only ids, no LazyLoading anywhere

Comment: 4. nope, I remotely execute it from external machine

Comment: 5. Unfortunately I have no freedom to chose DB, only Oracle :D

Comment: Hmm. Then I guess, you should start your Debugger and figure out where the code hangs. Maybe Hibernate still loads the whole object tree, even if the displayed query doesn't looks like this happens. Who knows. I already had lot's of cases where I ended up crying *Why, Hibernate, Why you do this to me? Whyyyy?*

Comment: Do you mean debugging into hibernate stuff?

Comment: Place a breakpoint inside your JPA Repository, and then step forward, forward, forward. Then you should be able to find the piece of code that takes a lot longer than the blink of an eye. Hope you find the error soon.

Comment: #4 could still be an issue depending on exactly how the application and database tool select records.  Maybe the application has an unusually low prefetch size; if it's gathering data one-row-at-a-time there will be a lot of extra network overhead.

Comment: @JonHeller prefetch size was set to 10. After I changed it to 100 for this particular query it speed up by 15%. Still not as fast as on DB, but far better. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, expanding the jdbc `fetchSize` property resolved the issue for me:

```java
// adding the fetchSize QueryHint for the query
@QueryHints(@QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.fetchSize", value="200"))
@Query("SELECT person.uuid FROM ....")
Set<String> findByGrandParentId(final String parentId);

// or set it globally, e.g., through application.properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size=200
```

Through profiling, found that the bottleneck occurred while matching each ResultSet row to Entity object. Seems that each round trip to the DB slow down the overall performance in my case.

From [Oracle JDBC Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#JJDBC28611) (emphasis mine):

> **By default, when Oracle JDBC runs a query, it retrieves a result set**
> **of 10 rows at a time** from the database cursor. This is the default
> Oracle row fetch size value. You can change the number of rows
> retrieved with each trip to the database cursor by changing the row
> fetch size value.
>
> Standard **JDBC also enables you to specify the number of rows fetched**
> **with each database round-trip for a query**, and this number is referred
> to as the fetch size. In Oracle JDBC, the row-prefetch value is used
> as the default fetch size in a statement object. Setting the fetch
> size overrides the row-prefetch setting and affects subsequent queries
> run through that statement object.